# Set master page file using function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change masterpagefile using another class function

Example:

```
public class XYZClass 
{
    public void CheckLogin(object ses,bool ipb,ref MasterPage page)
    {
        if (!(ses == null))
        {
            if (ses.ToString() == "Admin")
                page.MasterPageFile = "~/Admin.master";
            else
                page.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPage.master";
        }
        else 
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/frmLogin.aspx");
        }
    }
}

public partial class frmDoctorHistory : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    BLLcheckLogin checkLogin = null;    
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkLogin = new BLLcheckLogin();
        checkLogin.CheckLogin(Session["usertype"], IsPostBack, ref MasterPageFile);
    }

}
```

and I call this function from another aspx source file, and it gives me an error like 
"A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter".

Comment: MasterPage is an object, so it doesn't need to be passed by reference. Remove the "ref" from your method declaration and method call to resolve that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the Master Page no later than in the `PreInit` event.

See the code sample from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c8y19k6h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as a reference.

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/NewMaster.master";
}
```

You have to rewrite your current code as:

```
public void CheckLogin(object ses,bool ipb, Page page)
{
    if (!(ses == null))
    {
        if (ses.ToString() == "Admin")
            page.MasterPageFile = "~/Admin.master";
        else
            page.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPage.master";
    }
    else 
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/frmLogin.aspx");
    }
}

protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkLogin = new BLLcheckLogin();
    MasterPage mp;
    checkLogin.CheckLogin(Session["usertype"], IsPostBack, this);
}
```

I altered your code to pass in the `Page` rather than the `MasterPageFile` property. Ref isn't necessary any more then.

Comment: but i have a class which has function which changes masterpagefile. and i call this function from aspx source file

Comment: But you can't do this from an event after PreInit. It's too late.

Comment: No, i have simple class like business logic. and that class has function which has those codes. and that function called using object

Comment: But from that event that is called then?

Comment: that only i want to know, how can i do

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the OP is passing the MasterPage object, whereas you are passing the *page* object, and that you are dropping the `ref` keyword since it's not actually required in this scenario.

Comment: Thanx frnd, i got my solution, Patrick Hofman and Obsidian Phoenix